# google analytics - googlebot cant access site

Tags: google-analytics, googlebot

Sorry if this is the incorrect area.

I develop websites using Yootheme and Rockettheme. they have a coded area in the backend where you simply enter the code from Analytics.

however lately im getting emails stating the following;

**Message summary**

Webmaster Tools sent you the following important messages about sites in your account. To keep your site healthy, we recommend regularly reviewing these messages and addressing any critical issues.

http://www.anigmabeauty.co.nz/: Googlebot can't access your site

Over the last 24 hours, Googlebot encountered 1 errors while attempting to connect to your site. Your site's overall connection failure rate is 50.0%.

You can see more details about these errors in Webmaster Tools.

---

I've deleted them and re-added the websites, works for a while then does the same thing. Any ideas on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

When I open http://www.anigmabeauty.co.nz/ I get **303 See other** redirect. It may cause the issue since [303 redirect is not so good for SEO](http://sharkseo.com/nohat/303-redirects-seo/).

Try to replace 303 redirect with 302 redirect.

Comment: Hi teddy, this sounds stupid but how do I do this? as I just see the website.

Comment: Most likely web server itself does this 303 redirect. You could try to replace it with 301 redirect. If you use Apache server try to configure redirect on server using [Apache Web Server Configuration for Web Site Redirection](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ApacheRedirect.html) and here is [a link for IIS](http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/iis7-redirect-windows-server-2008)